# Combining between CON and Focal function in ArcGIS raster calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, con, focal-statistics

How do you write this code in the raster calculator for ArcGIS 10.2?

```py
CON(FOCALMIN([Burning], WEDGE, 4, 285, 345 ) == -1 , -1, [Burning])
```

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent syntax for the Raster Calculator would be:

```py
Con("myRaster.tif","myRaster.tif",-1,(FocalStatistics("myRaster.tif",NbrWedge(4,285,345),"MINIMUM")== -1))
```